# Radio button icon overlaps on text only in Android 4.2.2 devices.

Tags: android, text, radio-button

This is my code:

```
<RadioButton
        android:id="@id/all_questions_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:button="@drawable/icon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>
```

This code works perfectly fine in devices with android version below 4.2.2, but in device with android 4.2.2 the text is placed below the radio button icon.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i have fixed it by myself, added `android:paddingRight="-30dp"` to the xml and now the icon does not overlap on text.

Hope it will help some one in future.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: no its not working for 4.2.2 . Please give any other suggestion for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
  <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/all_questions_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:button="@drawable/icon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Comment: i have to go with weight,

Comment: No its still the same :(